# Spring Boot MySql Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have spring boot app and deployed to a remote server. The app runs on my computer. MySQL connection URL, user name and password are the same local and remote MySQL. DB and app in same machine!!

I checked my connection info and executed about below commands.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON burrda.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

My `application.properties` is below.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/burrda
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password= password
```

When apps runs I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

I'm not getting these exceptions `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` (using password: YES) or `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` (using password: NO)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.

The solution which worked for me

1. `Create` a new user
2. `Grant` this new user privileges of your database :

```
create user '<new_user_name>'@'localhost' identified by '<new_user_password>';
grant all privileges on <your_db_name>.* to '<new_user_name>'@'localhost' identified by '<new_user_password>';
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue while creating Spring Boot Application. I tried below :           
           create user 'boot'@'localhost' identified by 'boot';
           grant all privileges on mydb.* to 'boot'@'localhost'; 
           FLUSH PRIVILEGES;                                              But This is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear from your question, does DB runs in same machine where web application is running? If no, you need to provide IP address of the remote machine where the web application is running in the `GRANT` command.

Comment: DB and app in same machine.